# Blender 2.8 scene collection not update when adding new objects

Tags: modeling

Scene view seems not to update regardless how many components I add.

First image (have a cylinder and a plane (with a modifier)):

[image]

Second image, same but added a cube as well:

[image]

If any of the components overlap one another I can no longer select them individually (only the result of the overlap). Why?

Comment: Hello, could you explain what you would like to update in the scene view ?

Comment: Every time an object is added it should have a distinct reference (Plane, Plane.001, Cube, Cube.001, etc.). Right now, every component is lapped over the previous one; blender does not seem to differentiate between them (scale one, you scale the other, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tldr** : Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle between edit mode and object mode.

Blender has two separate modes for editing **objects (object mode)** and editing **geometry (edit mode)**.

Right now you are adding more geometry to the same object, in edit mode. In edit mode, you can add the same default primitives (cylinder, sphere, cube...) as in object mode, but this will not create a new object, only add to the existing object's geometry.

If you want to create new actual objects, you need to toggle the mode into **object mode** with <kbd>TAB</kbd> or click the foldout menu in the top left of your 3D view.

Incidentally, if you select two or more objects in **object mode**, then go into edit mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>, you will be able to edit all of the objects' geometry at once *(Since Blender 2.80)*.